# 'The requested URL could not be retrieved' when trying to make a Callout

Tags: webservices

I'm using a service where I pass a URL with a zip code, and in return I get the address of a postal code. However I am getting this message, in fact the service does not return an exception, but that message.

The requested URL could not be retrieved

Actually mesagem return comes in an HTML format.

Example: req.setHeader ('Content-Type', 'application / x-www-form-urlencoded');

Can anyone help?

```
try{
    String retorno;
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('http://m.correios.com.br/movel/buscaCepConfirma.do?cepEntrada=06853500&tipoCep=&cepTemp=&metodo=buscarCep');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setCompressed(false);
    req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    Http h = new Http();
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

    retorno = 'Mensagem de Retorno : ' + res.getBody();
    System.debug(retorno);

}

catch( Exception e ){
 System.debug('Mensagem de Erro : ' + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full HTML response? The HTTP status code and full error message will be helpful. The status code will either be 2xx, 4xx, or 5xx.

Comment: Hey Mike,
 Can you pass your e-mail, because I was trying post code here and code is very long.

Comment: Sorry. Can you trim it down to just the relevant section?

Comment: Is cepEntrada sensitive data? Like a private account number unique to you?

Comment: The response : The requested URL could not be retrieved -

Comment: POST /movel/buscaCepConfirma.do?cepEntrada=06853500&amp;tipoCep=&amp;cepTemp=&amp;metodo=buscarCep HTTP/1.1
SFDC_STACK_DEPTH: 1
User-Agent: SFDC-Callout/29.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Host: m.correios.com.br
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive

Comment: <LI>Missing or unknown request method
<LI>Missing URL
<LI>Missing HTTP Identifier (HTTP/1.0)
<LI>Request is too large
<LI>Content-Length missing for POST or PUT requests
<LI>Illegal character in hostname; underscores are not allowed

Answer (score 4):

It appears you are doing an HTTP POST rather than a GET. So rather than using the query string parameters you should be setting the body of the request.

I tried playing with the web site in question using a browser. Seems you can just set them as required.
[image: POST Form Data]

[setBody(String)](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_HttpRequest_setBody.htm) is one method you can use. E.g.

```
try {
    String retorno;
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('http://m.correios.com.br/movel/buscaCepConfirma.do');
    // NOTE: More the query string parameters into the POST Body.
    req.setBody('cepEntrada=06853500&tipoCep=&cepTemp=&metodo=buscarCep');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setCompressed(false);
    req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    Http h = new Http();
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

    retorno = 'Mensagem de Retorno : ' + res.getBody();
    System.debug(retorno);

} catch( Exception e ){
    System.debug('Mensagem de Erro : ' + e.getMessage());
}
```

Response extract:

> <div class="caixacampobranco">
>               <span class="resposta">Logradouro: </span>
>               <span class="respostadestaque">
>                   Rua Itanhaém
>               </span><br/>
>               <span class="resposta">Bairro: </span><span   class="respostadestaque">Vila João Montesano</span><br/>
>               <span class="resposta">Localidade / UF: </span>
>               <span class="respostadestaque">
>                   Itapecerica da Serra
>                   /SP
>               </span><br/>
>               <span class="resposta">CEP: </span><span   class="respostadestaque">06853500</span><br/>
>           <div style="text-align: right;" class="mopcoes   orientacao"><span>Opções <img style="position: relative right:0px;" src="images/template/mais.png"/></span></div>
>       </div>

Comment: Eh? `req.setMethod('POST');` - but you are the one with 200 OK at the end of the day! Nice.

Comment: @user320 Yes, you had it doing the POST as the website does, but the parameters needed to be in the POST body rather than on the query string as you would otherwise do with a GET request.

Comment: dohhh'ahhh - blind as a bat over here, cheers!

Comment: @user320 No problem :) If you feel this has answered your question there will be a tick mark next to the voting buttons that you can use to indicate the question has been answered. This makes it easier for future site users to find the correct answer.

Comment: Daniel hell I'd tick it if I could! ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help, worked perfectly here. Because EndPoint has put as parameter in the request. Again thank you for your attention, and the speed too. (((: